# Django rest filter by serializermethodfield with custom filter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

As declared in question title, i got task to filter results by field not presented in model but calculated by serializer.

The model:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Tag,
        related_name='recipe_tags'
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='author_recipes'
    )
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(
        Ingredient,
        related_name='recipe_ingredients'
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField()
    text = models.TextField()
    cooking_time = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        validators=[MinValueValidator(1)]
    )

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-id",)
        verbose_name = "Recipe"
        verbose_name_plural = "Recipes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is the view code:

```
class RecipeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrAuthorOrReadOnly, ]
    serializer_class = RecipeInSerializer
    pagination_class = LimitPageNumberPagination
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['tags', ]
    filter_class = RecipeFilter
```

Serializer:

```
class RecipeOutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tags = ManyRelatedField(child_relation=TagSerializer())
    author = CustomUserSerializer()
    ingredients = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_favorite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    is_in_shopping_cart = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        fields = '__all__'
        model = Recipe

    def get_ingredients(self, obj):
        ingredients = IngredientAmount.objects.filter(recipe=obj)
        return GetIngredientSerializer(ingredients, many=True).data

    def get_is_favorite(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if request.user.is_anonymous:
            return False
        return Favorite.objects.filter(recipe=obj, user=request.user).exists()

    def get_is_in_shopping_cart(self, obj):
        request = self.context.get("request")
        if not request or request.user.is_anonymous:
            return False
        return ShoppingCart.objects.filter(recipe=obj, user=request.user).exists()
```

And custom filter code:

```
class RecipeFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
    tags = ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(
        field_name='tags__slug',
        to_field_name="slug",
        queryset=Tag.objects.all()
    )

    favorite = BooleanFilter(field_name='is_favorite', method='filter_favorite')

    def filter_favorite(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.filter(is_favorite__exact=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['tags', ]
```

Target is is_favorited field that return boolean value. I tried writing func in custom filter class that return queryset but didnt work, neither documentation helped me with examples. Hope for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use queryset annotate:

```
from django.db import models
from rest_framework import serializers

class RecipeViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        user_id = user.id if not user.is_anonymous else None
        return Recipe.objects.all().annotate(
            total_favorite=models.Count(
                "favorite",
                filter=models.Q(favorite__user_id=user_id)
            ),
            is_favorite=models.Case(
                models.When(total_favorite__gte=1, then=True),
                default=False,
                output_field=BooleanField()
            )
        )


class RecipeOutSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer)
    is_favorite = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = (
            # ...
            is_favorite,
        )

class RecipeFilter(rest_framework.FilterSet):
    favorite = BooleanFilter(field_name='is_favorite')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Tried your proposal, but got the error `Cannot resolve keyword 'favorite' into field. Choices are: author, author_id, cooking_time, favorite_recipe, id, image, ingredients, name, recipe_amount, recipe_cart, tags, text`. Added models code to the question

Comment: My bad, favorite is related_name in your Receipe to Favorite. So chage it to `favorite_recipe`. Like: 
`models.Count("favorite_recipe", filter=models.Q(favorite_recipe__user_id=user_id))`

Comment: model `Favorite` must has relation to `Receipe`. Then use `related_name`, you defined in `Favorite`.

Comment: the error is gone, but filtering not working also, the query is `http://localhost:800/api/recipes/?page=1&limit=6&is_favorited=1`

Comment: yea, related name is 'favorite_recipe'

Comment: ReceipeFilter change to: `is_favorited = BooleanFilter(field_name='is_favorite')`

Comment: Still not working, got not favorited recipes listed by this query. Also noticed that param is_favorite in recipe is false, even if record in favorite table exists

Comment: In `RecipeViewSet`, it should`filterset_class = RecipeFilter` not `filter_class = ...`
Note that using `filterset_fields` and `filterset_class` together is not supported. 
So also move your filter `tags` to RecipeFilter.

Comment: Damn, still not filtering, either filed is false i got recipes listed. And still false on recipes that are favotited